# Excel function that calculate results from two cells depending on which cell is entered before the other

Tags: excel

Is there an excel function that calculate results from two cells depending on which cell is entered before the other?

We have a site in which workers do two operations, let's call them **A**&**B**.

For each operation, there is a different policy for payment for overtime.

let's say the output for the two operations will be shown in Cells **A**&**B**, and calculation of the payment for overtime will be shown in cell **C**.

So, if the cell **A** is entered before cell **B**, if there is an overtime, the payment policy in cell **C** will be calculated as per operation **B** policy, as it is the one causing the overtime. and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), then you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event to store the "Date/Time Modified" on a second (hidden) worksheet, like so:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheet2.Range(Target.Address).Value = Now()
End Sub
```

This would then let you include your "time sheet" in the formula, like this:

```vb
=IF(Sheet2!A1 < Sheet2!B1, "First was " & A1 & ", then " & B1, "First was " & B1 & ", then " & A1)
```

(Obviously, that is just a rough example, and doesn't take into account things like when only 1 of the cells has had data entered, or clearing dates when you delete data)